# Pass a function body/defintion as parameter to a function call in golang

Tags: function, go, parameter-passing

I am come across the following question recently in using golang. Is it ok to pass a function body to a function call, like javascript. 
e.g. `setTimeout(function(i){console.log("input:", i)}, 1000).`

It's pretty common to pass an anonymous function to another function in javascript. I was wondering if is the same in go?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type HandlerFunc func(int)

func main() {
    // define a function as object/variable?
    hnd := func(in int){
        fmt.Println("func handler returns input", in);
    }
    a:=HandlerFunc(hnd) //pass function object/variable to type HandlerFunc
    a(10)

    // pass function body directly to type HandlerFunc
    b:=HandlerFunc(func(_in int){
        fmt.Println("another func handler returns input", _in);
    })
    b(100)

    fmt.Println("Hello, playground")
}
```

They both works, but I was wondering if there is any difference between these two use, And which one is more preferable?

Comment: You are not passing functions in your code,  you just store function values in local variables, which then you call. See this related question: [First class functions in Go](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358031/first-class-functions-in-go)

Comment: It makes no difference.

Comment: Thanks @icza. I felt it should be no difference though, one of my colleagues seems to think otherwise. What I am curious about is that I couldn't found any piece of code online writing in the second style while it's so common in Javascript(I just switch from Javascript to Golang a couple of weeks ago). Besides, there's no mentioning the heap & stack in Golang's spec, it looks that Golang is smart enough to dynamically allocate memory so that users don't care the memory leaking like c/c++. Am I right?

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, use the one that better fits your style.